# How to use variable of provider to another provider in ionic2/3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have declare a variable ( `isConnection: boolean;` ) to check network connection and assign value as true and false in such functions on same provider named as 'network'.

Now I want to use the same variable in my another provider named as 'service'.  I want to check value of variable(isConnection) is true or false. 
I have imported the 'network' provider into 'service' provider.

can any one help how I can check value of variable( isConnection ) in 'service' provider ?

Comment: Could you please add the code related to those two services?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject 'network' provider into 'service' provider's constructor. Then you can access 'network' provider's members.

```
constructor (private network : network){
}

TestFunction () {
  console.log(this.network.isConnection);
 }
```